# Angular RXJS, how do I get all data in subscribe after using multiple mergeMap calls (sequentially)?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to get all data similar to how 'forkJoin' does it after making multiple HTTP calls sequentially using MergeMap.

```
this.dataService.getData1().pipe(
      mergeMap(response1 => this.dataService.getData2()),
      mergeMap(response2 => this.dataService.getData3()),
      mergeMap(response3 => this.dataService.getData4()),
    ).subscribe(

    //How do I get response1, response2, response3 and response4 here?

 )
```

Answer (score 2):

If no observable's parameter depend on the previous call

you can use `concat`, which will play the observables is a sequence, each time waiting on the previous to finish (unlike `merge`)

```
var arr = [
  this.dataService.getData1(),
  this.dataPublicationsService.getData2(),
  this.dataPublicationsService.getData3(),
  this.dataPublicationsService.getData4(),
];
concat(...arr).pipe(toArray()).subscribe((a) => console.log(a));
```

If each call depends on the previous one there is no "clean" way to do it, you have to pass the data youself.

One way to achieve this is use `forkJoin` and the spread operator

```
class Foo {
  dataService: { getData1: () => Observable<number> };
  dataPublicationsService: {
    getData2: () => Observable<string>;
    getData3: () => Observable<number>;
    getData4: () => Observable<object>;
  };

  bar() {
    this.dataService
      .getData1()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((response1) =>
          forkJoin([of(response1), this.dataPublicationsService.getData2()])
        ),
        mergeMap((rest) => // rest is [number, string]
          forkJoin([of([...rest]), this.dataPublicationsService.getData3()])
        ),
        mergeMap((rest) => rest is [number, string, number]
          forkJoin([of(...rest), this.dataPublicationsService.getData4()])
        )
      )
      .subscribe((rest) => {
         // [number, string, number, object]
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: So forkJoin combines them all despite it being separate calls? Never knew that

Comment: the `rest` variable is a new array with the result of the previous `forkJoin`, so each time it will have a new value. No magic here !

Comment: Also please see my edit, If you don't need to pass values between the observables

Comment: So complicated!!  but thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm wondering why not use concat for this?

Comment: Just tested this and it does not work sorry, it gives an array of an array in the subscribe rest result

Comment: maybe flatMap your result ?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new here. I don't know what that does.

Comment: It will flatten your array, please see [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUBtdBGAugGgAJ0AmPAZhx3gDNoBDAFwFk6AHVYAgXgD4DgAlAKA)